# How can I use a Promise to retry loading a MediaElement in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, html5-audio, es6-promise

I am trying to implement some retry logic to handle cases where an `<audio />` element encounters a network error ([`HTMLMediaElement.error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/error)) in TypeScript React. So far I have a basic retry which updates the `src` on the audio element, which seems to force it to re-fetch.

I've been trying to get Promises to work for a couple of hours but I'm struggling to map the generic examples online (usually in JavaScript) to my specific implementation in TypeScript.

Here's the relevant code from what I have so far:

```
private element: HTMLAudioElement | null = null;    

public componentDidMount() {
  if (this.element !== null) {
    this.element.addEventListener("error", this.retry, false);
  }
}

private readonly retry = () => {
  if (this.element !== null && this.element.error !== null) {
    if (this.element.error.code === 2 && this.props.src !== undefined) {
      this.element.src = this.props.src;
    }
  }
};

public render() {
  const { src } = this.props;
  return (
    <audio ref={ref => (this.element = ref)} src={src} />
  );
}
```

How can I replace this code with a Promise-based TypeScript solution with timed max retries, e.g. 3 retries with 5 seconds between each?

Comment: How do you know that Promise-based code will fix whatever problem it is you are having? What is the problem you're trying to *fix*? Is this code *broken* in any way?

Comment: @JaromandaX It's not so much broken, other than the fact that it continues retrying indefinitely. If the network error is not intermittent, then the client will continue retrying forever, which is not ideal. I'd prefer to try, say, 5 times over a minute, and then give up. Promises seem like the correct solution but I'm having difficulty getting them to work here.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could track the number of load errors to achieve your requirements, with the following changes:

```
private element: HTMLAudioElement | null = null;    
private loadAttempts: number = 0;

public componentDidMount() {
  if (this.element !== null) {
    this.element.addEventListener("error", this.retry, false);
  }
}

private readonly retry = () => {

  if(this.loadAttempts >= 2) { 
     return;
  }

  if (this.element !== null && this.element.error !== null) {
    if (this.element.error.code === 2 && this.props.src !== undefined) {

      // Wait for 5 seconds before attempting another reload
      setTimeout(() => {

        this.element.src = this.props.src;
        this.element.load(); // Best pratice
        this.loadAttempts ++;

      }, 5000) // Delay for 5 seconds before attempted retry
    }
  }
};

public render() {
  const { src } = this.props;
  return (
    <audio ref={ref => (this.element = ref)} src={src} />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So I did think of this too, however, the issue here is that the attempts will happen in quick succession. It would be nice to space them out a bit so you could do say, 5 in a minute, rather than 5 in 5 seconds.

Comment: You're welcome :) Just noticed that part of your question - have updated answer to account for the delay - does this work for you?

Comment: Thanks! I'm still keen on a Promise-based solution since I'd like to learn more about those. FYI the only change I needed to make for your answer is another null check for `this.element` and another undefined check for `this.props.src` inside the setTimeout, since they could have changed.

Comment: No problems, I will try and remember to revisit this tomorrow if you'd be interested in a promise based solution?

Comment: That would be awesome!